# Babylon can't recognize text on Firefox & IE 9

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-9, ocr, babylon

Before I upgraded to Firefox 4 & IE 9, Babylon was succesfully recognizing text on those browsers. After the upgrade, it cannot recognize text anymore. I've played with the OCR Optimization in the advanced settings, but it didn't help. Babylon works well out of these browsers, though.

Is there a workaround or solution to this problem?

*Note: I'm on Firefox 44 and the problem continues.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I haven't used Babylon since it became non-Firefox-friendly but today I tried something which worked. Here is what I did:

I have installed the latest version (Babylon 10) on my PC while Firefox window was open. As soon as the installation was completed, a page was opened in Firefox which asked me if I wanted to install **"Babylon Translation Activation Tool"**. I clicked "Yes" and it installed that extension on Firefox. After I restarted Firefox, I tested Babylon on Firefox and it worked!

Here is a screeny of that Firefox extension. It is weird that when I search for that extension in Firefox extensions database, it cannot be found. Hope that helps.

[image: screeny]

---

I found the following [post](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2140499) belonging to user "wimyogya" while searching the web for a clue:

> Babylon Support earlier informed me
>   that at this moment they do not
>   support IE9, Chrome 10beta and Firefox
>   4. They recommend temporary browser downgrade.
>
> Later I got the answers to my
>   additional questions:
>
> 1. Our developing department is already working to make Babylon 9
>      compatible with IE9, Chrome 10 and
>      Firefox 4, and it should take about
>      3-4 weeks.
> 2. Babylon Company is making the adaptations.
> 3. Only users of Babylon 9 and users who purchased Babylon 8 in grace
>      period, from the 1st of December of
>      2010, will be eligible to get the
>      update.
>
> Seems my Babylon 7 becomes pretty
>   useless :(

Too bad!

Comment: I had to downgrade my Firefox from v4 to v3.6.16. :(

Answer (score 0):

Only an upgrade from Babylon will solve this issue. After contacting Babylon`s support team, they claim that IE 9 is still beta and thus not supported. Funny but sad.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally found a temporary solution to this. I don't know if it will work for you but I hope so.

Select the word you want to translate in Firefox 4 and instead of right-click+ctrl use the <kbd>F10</kbd> key. Babylon will recognize the word and show you the translation.

I am using Babylon v8 r36, Firefox 4, Windows 7.

Comment: Babylon 8.1.0 r16 here. F10 only brings the Babylon window; it does not read the words.

Comment: Does not work with version 9.0.2(r2), as-well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for Google Chrome (howbeit it is not useful for me as I don't use Chrome):

**Disable ClearType** feature of Windows to solve the problem. In this way, Babylon can recognize texts in Google Chrome.

That being done in Firefox 4, Babylon captures only parts of words, not full words as before; so this workaround is not working for Firefox 4.

Answer (score 0):

lingoes (2.8.1) is very similar to Babylon and it is free and better text Capture Capabilities:

- There are plugins for firefox and chrome here
  http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/plugins.htm
- IE9 is supported out of the box
- Acrobat Reader **Professional** is also supporter (not the free
  reader version)