# Turn off Mozilla Firefox warning that there are new Firefox add-ons

Tags: firefox-extensions, notifications

Time to time Firefox pops up and says there are updates for your browser (especially add-ons). How can I change this so that it doesn't pop up this question any more, and only updates the add-ons quietly?

I'm thinking about older people who have a hard time using computers.

**Q**: Are there any solutions to quietly update the Firefox add-ons in the background?

OS: Scientific-Linux / Windows XP

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under 'Options' there's a tab describing what to do with updates (I don't have FF on this machine so can't tell you exactly what the tab name is). One of the options says something like 'update without asking'.

Comment: Firefox 3.6 -> http://i.imgur.com/jMFnd.png not good

Comment: At the risk of sounding supercilious, it's probably time for an upgrade. I don't know if there's a way to do what you want in a version of FF that far back.

Comment: FF 3.6 is not that far back and still good. I still use FF 3.6 because of the problem in [this question](http://superuser.com/q/261319/13567).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=V0f8u38e

Comment: FF3.6 was released January 21st 2010, so that's 21 months ago (roughly). We're now on FF7, with FF8 already on the horizon, so although in elapsed time it's not ancient, it's a long time in the lifecycle of the product. Updates to it now consist largely of bugfix and stability issue solutions. So to resolve your update problem, you'll have to upgrade - and hopefully your plugin dependency will have been resolved since March (check first though!).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Simple_Firefox_build

Answer (score 3):

You can

- disable Firefox's automatic check for updates in the **options -> advanced -> update**, or
- set it to update automatically (in the said pane) + [silently](http://kb.mozillazine.org/App.update.silent).

[Update notifier extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/update-notifier/) has an option to just install extensions's updates when they're available.

---

If you want to keep Firefox's "classic" interface but still get latest security updates, you could try the [Mozilla SeaMonkey suite](http://www.seamonkey-project.org). It has the updates check and auto-installation option built-in. The *preferences -> advanced -> software installation* section will include options for auto-updates for extensions and browser:

[image]

If you don't see them for browser then you [can set it](http://kb.mozillazine.org/App.update.silent) in about:config