# How to set Firefox to be "silent"?

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turn off Mozilla Firefox warning that there are new Firefox add-ons](https://superuser.com/questions/342847/turn-off-mozilla-firefox-warning-that-there-are-new-firefox-add-ons)

Firefox sometimes pops-up stating that there are updates for it, or an Add-on has been updated, etc.

How can make Firefox silent, so that it will only update itself/add-ons in the background, and doesn't pops-up with a message??*1

```
in the "about:config"

app.update.silent;false
```

setting this to true? what does it do?

*1 = because non-IT people will use PCs, and they don't know what to do, when a message pops up..

p.s.: Firefox 3.6/Scientific Linux

Comment: just set it to _never to check for updates_. (it will not pop up any messages but you'll have to run check for updates manually)

Comment: but I do want updates automatically :\

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27113/why-are-there-firefox-3-6-in-the-linux-repositories

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/update-notifier/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For preference setting [app.update.silent](http://kb.mozillazine.org/App.update.silent), *[Software Update:Checking For Updates](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Software_Update:Checking_For_Updates)* states:

> **true** all update prompting should be suppressed
>
> **false** show prompts to the user when there are events they should respond to

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/update-notifier/